# MATLAB: overwriting images using print function

Tags: image, matlab

I'm using the print function in MATLAB to write images of plots, something like that

```
print(figure(1),'-dpng','-r300',filename);
```

But apparently the images are not overwritten, and the original images stay. I was using saveas before, which seems to overwrite the images, but print gives me more output options. Any ideas?

UPDATE: I ended up deleting the files before the printing with a different function.

Comment: your code basically looks alright, it works for me also. And saved images are overwritten. To find the reason why it is not working for you, please provide more code.

Comment: probably the file is locked by other applications (or Matlab itself) so it can't be written.

Comment: Doing some tests, I think that is the problem. Somehow Matlab locks it so I cannot even delete it while in the program (using something like delete('filepath'). Why would that happen? The only thing I'm doing with the file is `print(figure(1),'-dpng','-r300',filename);`, and just once in all my code. The only time it saves the image is when there was none with the same name before (aka the first time). And how could I prevent or solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
im = frame2im(getframe(gcf,rec)); %Grabs image of plot as an image
imsave(im, filename);  %save image
```

That syntax may not be 100%, its a while since I've used it. 
Also be aware that this isn't perfect - I remember having issues with it grabbing a grey border around the edge of the plot. Also, I think the image may be based on a matlab screenshot.... just something to be aware of

Answer (score 0):

Saving figures in matlab is rather troublesome, especially if the saved image should look like the original figure.

For myself i found the solution in using export_fig.
It's one of the most downloaded fileexchange files - maybe you should give it a try:
http://www.mathworks.de/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig

A small introduction to export_fig can be found at:
https://github.com/ojwoodford/export_fig/blob/master/README.md